# Components doesn't re-render on Login

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a Login.js. The idea is when the user login, useNavigate routes the user back to Home.

```
import React from 'react';
import { auth, provider } from '../firebase-config';
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const Login = ({ isAuth, setIsAuth }) => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const signInWithGoogle = () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
            localStorage.setItem("isAuth", true);
            setIsAuth(true);
            navigate('../Home');
        })
    }

    return (
        <div class="ui container">
            <p>Sign in with Google to continue</p>
            <button class="ui primary button" onClick={() => signInWithGoogle()}>Login</button>
        </div>
    );

};

export default Login;
```

And this is my App.js. It has a button for signout that would redirect the user back to Login pages on signout.

```
import React from "react";
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from '../firebase-config';

const App = () => {

  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

  const signUserOut = () => {
    signOut(auth).then(() => {
      localStorage.clear();
      setIsAuth(false);
      window.location.pathname = "../pages/Login"
    })
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div class="ui secondary point menu">
        <div class="ui container">
          <Link class="active item" to="/">
            <h4> Home </h4>
          </Link>
          {!isAuth ? <Link class="item" to="/Login">
            <h4> Login </h4>
          </Link> : <span></span>}
          <div class="right menu">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="ui transparent icon input">
                <input />
                <i class="search link icon"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui two column very relaxed stackable grid">
          <div class="column">
            {isAuth ? "You are signed in" : "You need to sign in"}
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            {isAuth ? <button onClick={signUserOut}>Sign Out</button> : <span></span>}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/Login" element={<Login setIsAuth={setIsAuth} />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My problem is, when the user SignIn, useNavigate routed back to home and the link is ok, but the component of Home is not showing. The same thing happens when I clicked the signout button. Please kindly advise where should I look. Thanks!

Comment: Your route path is `'/'` and I believe that's what you need to navigate to. Not `'../Home'` You're navigating to the route not the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are navigating to paths that your app isn't rendering any content for. There is no `"..../Home"` path, I suspect you meant `navigate("/")` and the signout function is simply reloading the entire page to a path that isn't handled, likely you meant to use `navigate("/login", { replace: true })` there to redirect to the login page.

Login

```
import React from 'react';
import { auth, provider } from '../firebase-config';
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = ({ isAuth, setIsAuth }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
      localStorage.setItem("isAuth", true);
      setIsAuth(true);
      navigate('/', { replace: true }); // redirect to home "/" path
    });
  };

  return (
    <div class="ui container">
      <p>Sign in with Google to continue</p>
      <button class="ui primary button" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

App

```
import React from "react";
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import { useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from '../firebase-config';

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

  const signUserOut = () => {
    signOut(auth).then(() => {
      localStorage.clear();
      setIsAuth(false);
      navigate("/Login", { replace: true }); // redirect to login path
    })
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div class="ui secondary point menu">
        <div class="ui container">
          <Link class="active item" to="/">
            <h4> Home </h4>
          </Link>
          {!isAuth ? <Link class="item" to="/Login">
            <h4> Login </h4>
          </Link> : <span></span>}
          <div class="right menu">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="ui transparent icon input">
                <input />
                <i class="search link icon"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui two column very relaxed stackable grid">
          <div class="column">
            {isAuth ? "You are signed in" : "You need to sign in"}
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            {isAuth ? <button onClick={signUserOut}>Sign Out</button> : <span></span>}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/Login" element={<Login setIsAuth={setIsAuth} />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

Wrap the `App` component so it can use the `useNavigate` hook.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from '../App';

...

return (
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
);
```